# Disable visual editor based on role?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to disable visual editor form 'author' role form my wordpress site. 
Author only see text editor when write a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`user_can_richedit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_can_richedit/) filter to tell WP to disable rich editor for author only through this code (put this inside your *functions.php* file):

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    add_filter( 'user_can_richedit' , '__return_false', 50 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I make following function it's work.

```
function cp_disable_editor()
{
    if( current_user_can( 'author' ) )
    {
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
        update_user_meta( $user_ID, 'rich_editing', false );
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','cp_disable_editor');
```

Comment: That's extremely unefficient: every time an author load an administration page you update the meta in the database. The solution I proposed just make a conditional check - it didn't worked for you?